# how to read particular xml value using flex?

Tags: php, apache-flex, air, flash

I used HTTPService for reading xml, but I want only a particular xml field value like the 
first node id.

The `HTTPService` object is:

```
<mx:HTTPService result="getid(event)" id="xml_coupon" url="###" useProxy="false" resultFormat="e4x"/>
```

The `getid(event)` function is:

```
public function getid(evt:ResultEvent):void
{
    var id:number=evt.result.id;
    Alert.show(id.tostring);
}
```

The `getid` function shows all ids, but I want the first index id only. How can I read this? I tried `Alert.show(evt.getChildAt(1).id);` but it shows an error. If you know, please help me.

Comment: http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=13_Working_with_XML_04.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

hey do some thing like this

if xml is like this

```
<mx:XML id="usersXML">
  <root>
    <users>
      <user id="1" lovesDonuts="Yes">
        <firstname>Tariq</firstname>
        <lastname>Ahmed</lastname>
      </user>
      <user id="2" lovesDonuts="Yes">
        <firstname>Jon</firstname>
        <lastname>Hirschi</lastname>
      </user>
    </users>
  </root>
</mx:XML>
```

then do this

```
usersXML.users.user[1].firstname
```

for id

```
usersXML.users.user[1].@id
```

Comment: This is the right idea, but so there is no confusion, you are returning "Jon" and "2", not "Tariq" and "1". The first user is the [0] index.

Comment: hey welcome you recommend you to go through chapter 15 of Flex 3 in action for more tricks of E4X